# How to get data from an API into a database with different schemas?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, spring-boot, rest

Suppose you have an MS SQL Server which has a Database A {id, name, age} and I need to take this into an REST API. Now I want to map the values into another Database B{student_id, student_name, student_age} in PostgreSQL . How do I do it?
Also assume I have made the API from Database A and now only mapping is required.
The API is as follows:
[API goes like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFcQ5.png)

I have read about spring boot one to one mappings but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is Gulshan Negi

Well, you can extract the data from the MS SQL Server database, transform it to match the schema of the PostgreSQL database, load it into the PostgreSQL database, and then set up a REST API to query the data and return the desired results in order to map values from an MS SQL Server database to a PostgreSQL database and expose it through a REST API. Before loading the data into PostgreSQL, it is essential to ensure that it has been accurately transformed and that any potential issues, such as naming conflicts or mismatches between data types, have been resolved.

Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Again, not an answer. This makes no sense, in context of the question (and seems to be following a consistent pattern for all of your answers).